# Inherit from MasterPage

Tags: c#, asp.net

In a Web Form project, I using MasterPage for user Role and Other-Pages inherit from MasterPage.
I try to use this codes into the Load function in MasterPage :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string MyPage = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.Path);
        SqlDataReader RolePageDr = BLL.Users.RolesPage(MyPage);
        while (RolePageDr.Read())
        {
            string Rolepage = RolePageDr["Roles"].ToString();
            if (Page.User.IsInRole(Rolepage) != true)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/MsgPage.aspx");
            }
            else
                Response.Redirect(MyPage);
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is that when the user redirected to the Other-pages (For Example: AdminPage), this admin page inherited from MasterPage and this Load function run again and a again.

Comment: This problem occurred because of that.whenever we loan any page and if that page is inherited from master page then first of all our master page will load and IsPostBack always will be false.

Comment: And do you want to change master page as per the role type?

Comment: Have you looked into using global.asax event 'Application_AuthenticateRequest' instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will run again and again; that is the nature of stateless programming.  But what you can do is use session to store it, and then only reload it when session isn't there, as in:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string role;

        var sessionValue = Session["Roles"];
        if (sessionValue != null)
           role = sessionValue.ToString();

        else
        {
          string MyPage = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.Path);
          SqlDataReader RolePageDr = BLL.Users.RolesPage(MyPage);
          while (RolePageDr.Read())
          {
            role = RolePageDr["Roles"].ToString();
            Session["Roles"] = role;
          }
        }

        if (Page.User.IsInRole(Rolepage) != true)
        {
                Response.Redirect("~/MsgPage.aspx");
        }
        else
                Response.Redirect(MyPage);
    }
}
```

Session keeps the value and prevents constant checking of the database, but when it expires,  the page reloads it and stores it in session again.